Article in "Science" about event driven microscopy: Trouble understanding probabilities in a Poisson process?
I am going through this article: https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.ado8579
I am a microscopist trying to figure out how much sense is there in their claim that measuring the time until a certain number of counts has been achieved "gives more information" than measuring how many counts you get during a fixed interval of time.
The article is really about fundamental properties of a Poisson process. What is it better: counting how many electrons reach a detector during a given interval of time, or alternatively, counting how much time until we detect a fixed number of electrons.
In particular I have trouble understanding how they derive the following expression in the supplementary information:
$$P(p|n,t) = \frac{p^n t^{n+1} e^{-pt}}{\gamma (n+1,t)} $$
Where p is the scattering rate ($\lambda = pt$), n = number of electrons detected, t= time elapsed.
I have trouble understanding the conditional probability $P(p|n,t)$. To my understanding if n,t are given, then the measured scattering rate is p=n/t, so what does its probability mean?
Any help making sense of this is welcome.

The scattering rate is a parameter of your model, whereas the number of electrons detected and the time elapsed are measured quantities. They attempt to establish what the parameter value is based on the measurements. You could say that $\hat{p}=n/t$ is a measured rate, but it's not necessarily the "true" rate. Several parameter values for the model could in principle generate certain measured $n$ for instance if $t$ is fixed, or $t$ if $n$ is fixed. In a Bayesian fashion, they make a probability distribution for the parameter in terms of measured values.

Thank you for your response. I understand what you mean and that clarifies it a bit. I guess I still doubt in how this probability could be derived from P(n given t,p) and P(t given n,p), which is what they say they do in the article without showing the actual calculation.
